# Block A full height on left side with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have my interface which keep block A on left side (full height). I know I'm wrong with the actual implementation because block A is not correctly taking full height space, but I'm new with the `flex` property.

How to have block A exactly full height on left side ?

jsfiddle: [my implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/mf58bj40/2/)

```css
.container,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item,
.block {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.itemA {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
}

.itemB {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  flex: 1;
  display: none;
}

.itemD {
  flex: 1;
}

.itemB1,
.itemB2,
.itemB3 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item itemA">
    A
  </div>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="itemB">
      <div class="item itemB1">
        B1
      </div>
      <div class="item itemB2">
        B2
      </div>
      <div class="item itemB3">
        B3
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item itemD">
      D
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to also accommodate the padding and margin applied to the item. Try the below using `calc()`

```css
.container,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item,
.block {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.itemA {
  width: 30px;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  float: left;
}

.itemB {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.block {
  flex: 1;
  display: none;
}

.itemD {
  flex: 1;
}

.itemB1,
.itemB2,
.itemB3 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item itemA">
  A
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="itemB">
    <div class="item itemB1">
      B1
    </div>
    <div class="item itemB2">
      B2
    </div>
    <div class="item itemB3">
      B3
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block blockB1">
    Block B1
  </div>
  <div class="block blockB2">
    Block B2
  </div>
  <div class="block blockB3">
    Block B3
  </div>
  <div class="block blockD">
    Block D
  </div>

  <div class="item itemD">
    D
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but is there any way of  preventing using float: left and use only flex method ?

Comment: yes, for that you need to have a wrapper and then use flex for that. The same way you did for the right container. Another option is a grid.